# Easy to use command line wifi / networking tool

Tags: networking, wifi, network-interface, networkmanager

I consider myself mildly proficient with command line, and I'm sure if I tried hard enough, I'd eventually be able to connect to my wifi network using `ifconfig`, `iwconfig`, `dhclient`, etc. and lots of googling

But I was wondering if there is any linux command line tool that bundles all those network / wifi commands into one single command so that I can just type in the username and password (if applicable) and it'll do all the internal stuff for me?  Basically a command line utility that is as easy to use as the Network Manager gui tool most distros provide.

Ideally I'd want something as simple as `dowifimagic -u my_username -p my_password`

Comment: I suggest `wpa_supplicant`; you store config file in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`, and connect with `wpa_supplicant -B -i interfacename`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[NetworkManager](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/NetworkManager) (since you are already familiar with it) has a command line tool called `nmcli`. That might be what you are after.

Documentation **[here](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/23/html/Networking_Guide/sec-Connecting_to_a_Network_Using_nmcli.html)**. And **[here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/sec-Using_the_NetworkManager_Command_Line_Tool_nmcli.html)**. And from the superb Arch-Wiki **[here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager#nmcli)**.

Comment: Where the magic command is: `nmcli device wifi connect <SSID> password <password>`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [ceni](http://manual.aptosid.com/en/inet-ceni-en.htm)

"A Curses user interface for configuring network interfaces with ifupdown.
 Ceni can manage basic network interface ifupdown configuration stanzas for
 ethernet and wireless devices."

or [wicd-cli](https://launchpad.net/wicd)

"wired and wireless network manager - scriptable console client"